# How to add data labels to a graph created by google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, charts, google-visualization

Here is my code.

```
function createChart(){

  var data = Charts.newDataTable()
    .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, "month")
    .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, "A")
    .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, "B")
    .addRow(["Feb", 10, 5])
    .addRow(["Mar", 12, 3])
    .addRow(["Apr", 20, 5])
    .build();
   var chart = Charts.newBarChart()
      .setDataTable(data)
      .setStacked()
      .setOption('series', {
          0: {dataLabel: 'value'},
          1: {dataLabel: 'value'},
        })
      .setTitle('Sales per Month')
      .build();
  saveGraph2Drive(chart)

  return

}


function saveGraph2Drive(chart) {
  var folderId = 'xxxxx'; // Google Drive Folder ID
  var today = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 'Asia/Tokyo', 'YYYY-MM-dd');
  try {
    var graphImg = chart.getBlob();
    var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
    folder.createFile(graphImg).setName(today);
  } catch (e) {
    Browser.msgBox(e);
  }
}
```

I run `createChart()` in google apps script, and the following graph was saved to Drive.
[image: The graph without datalabes]

But, I need the following graph, which has data labes.
[image: The graph with data labels]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to add the data labels to the chart.

How about this modification?

In order to achieve above, it uses Class DataViewDefinitionBuilder.

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified, please modify as follows.

```
function createChart(){
  var annotations = [0,  // Added
    1, {calc: "stringify", sourceColumn: 1, type: "string", role: "annotation"},
    2, {calc: "stringify", sourceColumn: 2, type: "string", role: "annotation"},
  ];
  var dataViewDefinition = Charts.newDataViewDefinition().setColumns(annotations).build();  // Added

  var data = Charts.newDataTable()
    .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, "month")
    .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, "A")
    .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, "B")
    .addRow(["Feb", 10, 5])
    .addRow(["Mar", 12, 3])
    .addRow(["Apr", 20, 5])
    .build();
   var chart = Charts.newBarChart()
      .setDataTable(data)
      .setStacked()
      .setOption('series', {
          0: {dataLabel: 'value'},
          1: {dataLabel: 'value'},
        })
      .setTitle('Sales per Month')
      .setDataViewDefinition(dataViewDefinition)  // Added
      .build();

  saveGraph2Drive(chart)

  return

}
```

#### Result:

[image]

#### References:

- [Class DataViewDefinitionBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/data-view-definition-builder)
- [setDataViewDefinition()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/bar-chart-builder#setdataviewdefinitiondataviewdefinition)
- [Labeling columns](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart#labeling-columns)

  - I think that this document might be useful.

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It worked for me! Thank you so much.

Comment: @DggYuki Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.